# Exchange 2010 PST-Export fails

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, exchange-2010, powershell

I'm horribly failing at exporting Exchnange Mailboxes to PST files. Perhaps You are able to help me?

### The System

I'm running some legacy machines here. The one I'm currently working on (CurrentDC) is a Windows 2008 R2 Server with Exchange 2010 on it. Exchange seems to be poorly patched:

```
[PS] C:\>get-exchangeserver

Name                Site                 ServerRole  Edition     AdminDisplayVersion
----                ----                 ----------  -------     -------------------
OldDC                                    None        Enterprise  Version 6.5 (Bui...
CurrentDC           company.local        Mailbox,... Enterprise  Version 14.0 (Bu...
```

### The Problem

After some trouble I managed to get the Export-Mailbox command run:

```
[PS] C:\>Export-Mailbox -Identity marco -PSTFolderPath C:\ExchangeExport
```

According to several Websites that seems to be the right command to export the mailbox of the user "marco" to "C:\ExchangeExport".

But after running the command an error occurs (I'm sorry, it is the german version of Windows 2008 - but if you translate Fehler with error and Vorgang with process you should be prepared enough to go ;))

```
[PS] C:\Export-Mailbox -Identity marco -PSTFolderPath C:\ExchangeExport
Fehler für Marco S (Marco.S@company.de). Ursache: Fehler bei diesem Vorgang., Fehlercode: -2147467259.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (0:Int32) [Export-Mailbox], RecipientTaskException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 2317FD3A,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.ExportMailbox

RunspaceId                       : 44415363-371e-44a1-a682-61e6a9b90c86
Identity                         : company.local/Company User/Marco S
DistinguishedName                : CN=Marco S,OU=Company User,DC=company,DC=local
DisplayName                      : Marco S
Alias                            : marco
LegacyExchangeDN                 : /o=Erste Organisation/ou=Erste administrative Gruppe/cn=Recipients/cn=marco
PrimarySmtpAddress               : Marco.S@company.de
SourceServer                     : CurrentDC.company.local
SourceDatabase                   : Mailbox Database 0279110169
SourceGlobalCatalog              : CurrentDC
SourceDomainController           :
TargetGlobalCatalog              : CurrentDC
TargetDomainController           :
TargetMailbox                    :
TargetServer                     :
TargetDatabase                   :
MailboxSize                      : 0 B (0 bytes)
IsResourceMailbox                : False
SIDUsedInMatch                   :
SMTPProxies                      :
SourceManager                    :
SourceDirectReports              :
SourcePublicDelegates            :
SourcePublicDelegatesBL          :
SourceAltRecipient               :
SourceAltRecipientBL             :
SourceDeliverAndRedirect         :
MatchedTargetNTAccountDN         :
IsMatchedNTAccountMailboxEnabled :
MatchedContactsDNList            :
TargetNTAccountDNToCreate        :
TargetManager                    :
TargetDirectReports              :
TargetPublicDelegates            :
TargetPublicDelegatesBL          :
TargetAltRecipient               :
TargetAltRecipientBL             :
TargetDeliverAndRedirect         :
Options                          : Default
SourceForestCredential           :
TargetForestCredential           :
TargetFolder                     :
PSTFilePath                      : C:\ExchangeExport\marco.pst
RecoveryMailboxGuid              :
RecoveryMailboxLegacyExchangeDN  :
RecoveryMailboxDisplayName       :
RecoveryDatabaseGuid             :
StandardMessagesDeleted          : 0
AssociatedMessagesDeleted        : 0
DumpsterMessagesDeleted          : 0
MoveType                         : ExportToPST
MoveStage                        : Validation
StartTime                        : 05.10.2012 13:55:46
EndTime                          : 05.10.2012 13:55:46
StatusCode                       : -2147467259
StatusMessage                    : Fehler bei diesem Vorgang.
ReportFile                       : C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\Logging\MigrationLogs\export-Mailbox20121005-135545-8170000.xml
ServerName                       : CurrentDC.company.local
```

### What I have done

Well, I must say I'm quite clueless. I was wondering why MailboxSize is 0 - so I checked it:

```
[PS] C:\>Get-MailboxStatistics marco | ft DisplayName, TotalItemSize, ItemCount

DisplayName       TotalItemSize                  ItemCount
-----------       -------------                  ---------
Marco S           473 MB (496,011,572 bytes)          4173
```

Well, this i not 0 bytes - but I don't know what to do with this information.

Also I had a look at the ReportFile mentioned in the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<export-Mailbox>
  <TaskHeader>
    <RunningAs>NT-AUTORITÄT\SYSTEM</RunningAs>
    <Name>export-Mailbox</Name>
    <Type>ExportToPST</Type>
    <MaxBadItems>0</MaxBadItems>
    <Version>14.0.639.21</Version>
    <StartTime>10.05.2012 14:19:12</StartTime>
    <Options Identity="marco" PSTFolderPath="C:\ExchangeExport" DeleteContent="False" DeleteAssociatedMessages="False" GlobalCatalog="CurrentDC" MaxThreads="4" BadItemLimit="0" ValidateOnly="False" IncludeFolders="" ExcludeFolders="" StartDate="01.01.0001 00:00:00" EndDate="31.12.9999 23:59:59" SubjectKeywords="" ContentKeywords="" AllContentKeywords="" AttachmentFilenames="" SenderKeywords="" RecipientKeywords="" Locale="" />
  </TaskHeader>
  <TaskDetails>
    <Item MailboxName="Marco S">
      <Source>
        <Identity>company.local/Company User/Marco S</Identity>
        <DistinguishName>CN=Marco Sc,OU=Company User,DC=company,DC=local</DistinguishName>
        <DisplayName>Marco S</DisplayName>
        <Alias>marco</Alias>
        <LegacyExchangeDN>/o=Erste Organisation/ou=Erste administrative Gruppe/cn=Recipients/cn=marco</LegacyExchangeDN>
        <PrimarySmtpAddress>Marco.S@company.de</PrimarySmtpAddress>
        <SourceServer>CurrentDC.company.local</SourceServer>
        <SourceDatabase>Mailbox Database 0279110169</SourceDatabase>
        <IsResourceMailbox>False</IsResourceMailbox>
        <SourceGlobalCatalog>CurrentDC</SourceGlobalCatalog>
      </Source>
      <Target>
        <PSTFilePath>C:\ExchangeExport\marco.pst</PSTFilePath>
      </Target>
      <MailboxSize>0 B (0 bytes)</MailboxSize>
      <Duration>00:00:00</Duration>
      <Result IsWarning="False" ErrorCode="-2147467259">Fehler bei diesem Vorgang.</Result>
    </Item>
  </TaskDetails>
  <TaskFooter>
    <EndTime>10.05.2012 14:19:13</EndTime>
    <TotalSize>0 B (0 bytes)</TotalSize>
    <StandardMessagesDeleted>0</StandardMessagesDeleted>
    <AssociatedMessagesDeleted>0</AssociatedMessagesDeleted>
    <DumpsterMessagesDeleted>0</DumpsterMessagesDeleted>
    <Result ErrorCount="1" CompletedCount="0" WarningCount="0" />
  </TaskFooter>
</export-Mailbox>
```

Do you have any clue?

**`<UPDATE>`** Regarding to the answer from downthepub I tried to use UNC paths - no change. Also I tried installing the management tools to a client and run the scripts from there - no way, too. **`</UPDATE>`**

Thanks a lot for reading this mess!

Comment: Just a thought, could it be reporting mailbox size as zero because the account doing the export request doesn't have permission to access the mailbox?

Comment: @MikeAWood nice thought - I just tested this by opening the powershell with "Run as another user" and started ps as "company\marco". The result is exactly the same :(

Comment: Just another thought, I think you might need to give the task a UNC rather than a local path.  In the never version of Exchange 2010, using New-MailboxExportRequest, you have to use a UNC because of the way the export gets farmed out on the server(s).

Comment: downthepub mentioned UNC path in his answer too. I tested it with UNC paths but had no luck :(

Comment: check this link, you probably don't have the correct rbac settings.  http://www.korneel.nl/?p=28

Comment: to confirm the rbac issue check your app logs for rbac errors.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than 
`[PS] C:\>Export-Mailbox -Identity marco -PSTFolderPath C:\ExchangeExport`

use
`[PS] C:\>Export-Mailbox -Identity marco -PSTFolderPath \\server\share`
The target path needs to be passed as a UNC path rather than with drive letters.  Also, there's a bug with exporting when the [CAS role is installed](http://msexchangeguru.com/2010/11/13/e2010-export-mailbox/), so install the Management Tools to a separate computer and run the cmdlets from there.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but this doesn't work. Also I'm a little bit puzzled with the use of UNC pahts. The article you linked also uses "drive letter notation".

Comment: Good point, it was linked primarily for verbiage on the CAS/Export-PST bug, but now I notice the drive letter notation.  Sorry for any confusion!